# Sum values in HTML page using XQuery / XPath 2.0

Tags: java, xpath, xquery, xmlbeans

I have an HTML page like:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Hello</title></head>
  <body>
    <div id="foo">
      <h6>9</h6>
      <h6>3</h6>
      <h6>5</h6>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to use XQuery (or xpath 2.0) to sum the values in the <h6> elements. I'm using xmlbeans (with saxon as the engine) and I tried the following which just gives me a null pointer exception;

```
XmlObject xml = XmlObject.Factory.parse(xmlFile);
XmlCursor htmlCursor = xml.newCursor();
XmlCursor result = htmlCursor.execQuery("sum(for $val in $this//h6 return number($val))");

System.out.println(result.getObject());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the HTML page in a namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XPath Sum Function:

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(xmlFile);
XPath path = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
System.out.println(path.evaluate("sum(//h6)", doc));
```

prints:

```
17
```

Comment: That does work. I don't know why I didn't look at using the standard API's in the first place. I guess I didn't realize I could use XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 with the standard java libraries.

Comment: @codecraig: This expression is **also** XPath 1.0. And `evaluate` method is for DOM XPath 1.0 API

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing here but the `$this` in your query looks a bit odd.  In standard XQuery there is no variable in scope called `$this`. I assume you want the context item, so your query would look like:

```
sum(for $val in .//h6 return number($val))
```

or more simply:

```
sum(.//h6/number(.))
```

or just:

```
sum(.//h6)
```

Omitting the dot would mean that the XPath starts at the root of the document, not at the context item.

Comment: The reason for "$this" was b/c I was using xmlbeans.

Comment: @codecraig: No matter what is your XQuery engine, for using parameters into XQuery expressions, you need to declare them: `declare variable $this external;` . And then you would need to register or pass `this` parameter to the XQuery engine.